# Clarification Needed - Quick Start WordPress for Google App Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, caching, timthumb

I'm looking into setting up WordPress on the Google App Engine, but I'm searching for some clarification, as I am new to the Google App Engine.

I'm using this guide supplied by Google: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

This note is at the very bottom of the page:

> Note: You'll want to keep that local copy of WordPress handy, because you'll need it to install custom themes and plugins. Because of the security sandbox, your live WordPress site can not write to the local files -- they're static. This means the auto-installation of themes and plugins in the WordPress dashboard will only work in the local WordPress that you run on your own machine. So, remember to do all your installing locally, then re-deploy your WordPress app.

I have a few questions:

1. Will users be able to freely upload photos to WordPress with this method?
2. Will Caching plugins work?
3. Will Timthumb work?

If anyone could help me answer these questions (I'm sure the rest of the WP can benefit from this knowledge) that would be utterly wonderful.

Comment: 1. Yes, the photos are uploaded to Google Cloud Storage. 2. It comes with batcache, I don't know if other plugins will work. 3. Don't know.

Comment: Thank you! It sounds like it's worth testing

Comment: Any conclusions? Looking into running WP on AppEngine and have the same exact questions.